# Solving polynomial matrix equations over finite fields

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials

The concrete problem is this: Find triplets of distinct matrices $(A,B,C)$ of dimension $6\times 6$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ such that:

1. $A^2B=AB^2$
2. $C^2A=CA^2$
3. $B^3C=BC^3$

However, I'm also interested in how this can be done in a more general setting at least with other sets of equations; for now I can assume I always need triplets of square matrices of small dimension over a small finite field.

If it can be done with a well-known computer algebra system (esp. SAGE) it will be great.

Comment: Do you have any objection against taking $A=B=C$?

Comment: Yes, I should have said so explicitly.

Comment: http://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/42413-Matrix-Algebra-Over-Finite-Fields

Comment: You do realize that if you want the matrices to be invertible, then the first equation implies $A=B$, the second implies $C=A$,  and the third implies that $B^2=C^2$, which is actually a consequence of the two earlier ones. If you don't insist that the matrices should be invertible, then the easiest way is to follow azimut.

Answer (score 1):

The following three matrices give a solution to your initial problem:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\\
B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\\
C = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Many more solutions can be built in a similar way.