# In what areas where Polynomial Matrix (or matrix-coefficient polynomial) is being used?

Tags: polynomials, matrix-equations

Polynomials with coefficients over Fields (Real or Complex numbers) are commonly seen in many applications, but rare are the Polynomial Matrix (PM) or Polynomials with coefficient over (non-abelian Ring) Matrix.

For curiosity, I google on PM, however there isn't  any information on its application except the definition in: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_matrix

I would like to know in what areas, situations, problems, in which we use PM ?

Appreciate anyone who could enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

[Note] below the difference between Polynomial Matrix (PM) & Matrix Polynomial(MP) :

Let Aj (j = 0...n) be any square matrix. I be the unity matrix.

Polynomial Matrix (PM) : Eg. X² + Aj. X + Aj

Or

Matrix Polynomial (MP): Eg. (Aj)²+ 3.Aj + I

MP is just a combination of matrices Aj. We can apply Caley-Hamilton Theorem to simplify its computation.

PM is polynomial with coefficient in matrices Aj (j = 0...n).

Answer (score 1):

There are several polynomial matrix equations, for example the [Sylvester Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), the [Algebraic Riccati Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation), or
[Fermat's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625140/a-fermats-flt-look-like-for-matrices) and others. They have applications for various fields of mathematics and physics. There is a book book "*Matrix Polynomials*", of which the authors are I. Gohberg, P. Lancaster and L. Rodman.

Also on this site we find many posts asking about polynomial matrix equations:

[Solving polynomial matrix equations over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128337/solving-polynomial-matrix-equations-over-finite-fields)

[Solving a simple matrix polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827375/solving-a-simple-matrix-polynomial)

[Matrix Equation Simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410461/matrix-equation-simplification/2410494#2410494)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know of the Matrix Polynomials (MP) , what about Polynomial Matrix (PM) ? Any sources / books ?